# Excel.exe still running in Task Manager in C sharp

Tags: c#

I have a C sharp code which is not closing Excel.exe in Task manager.
excelApp.Quit() is not closing the Excel.exe in task manager , can someone suggest me how to close the Excel.exe in task manager

```
          ToolingStageSheet = mainWorkbook.Worksheets["Tool-Progressive"];
                        totalToolingCost = Convert.ToDecimal(ToolingStageSheet.Cells[38, 15].Value);
                        mainWorkbook.Save();
                        mainWorkbook.Close(0);
                        excelApp.Quit();
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mainWorkbook);
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
                        excelApp = null;
```

Comment: obvious question first. are you sure that code is being called?

Comment: also is this running interactively, can you see the UI? If you left unsaved workbooks then excel will be prompting to save them, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts

Answer (score 0):

You can do with **System.Diagnostics**.

Please try the following code.

```
  Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEl");
  int pid = processes[0].Id;
  Process pro = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
  pro.Kill();
```

Comment: what if the user opens two or more excel apps?

Comment: this does not ensure the "right" instance of Excel is closed, it can potentially close some other Excel process running in the system, not good.

Comment: Hi Ajay, Thanks for the solution, it's working fine in local system but in server when hosted I am facing issue, because I don't have access to kill process in server, can you suggest any solution.

Comment: @SrikanthReddyKatla, You will have run the .EXE file with Admin privileges.